# Generate random numer in python?

Tags: python

Each game (gameA and gameB) is random, and each of them has odds stacked against the player, each time either game is played, if you win, you win $1, if you lose, you lose $1.
I want to generate a random number from 0 to 1, if the number is less that 0.4 i lose, if it is bigger i win. Here is the code, but it gives me an error, can you help me please?
the question is:How much money do I lose playing this games?

```
import random
def testA():
    # game A
    gameA = random.random()
    if gameA>0.4   #error
    profitA=profitA+1
    end
    return profitA
def testB():    
    #game B    
    gameB = random.random()
    if gameB>0.4
    profitA=profitA+1
    end
    return profitB
def runTests(repititions):
    sumA = 0
    sumB = 0
    for i in range(repititions):
        profitA = testA()
        profitB = testB()
        sumA += profitA
        sumB += profitB

    return sumA, sumB
repititions = int(raw_input("Repititions: "))
sumA, sumB = runTests(repititions)

print sumA
print sumB
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How much money do I lose playing this games?

Comment: You need to add the exact error messages when you ask a question. Also, the syntax of the if statement looks incorrect. Try googling "Python conditional statements".

Comment: Furthermore, check what type random returns.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru read a Python book. Your code indicates that you have zero idea about Python syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two syntax errors, a spacing error, and you're using a keyword which doesn't exist.

```
if gameA>0.4   #<-- end this with a colon
profitA=profitA+1 #<-- needs more indent
end #<-- what is end?
```

All of that is repeated in `gameB`.

In addition:

- `profitA` and `profitB` aren't defined in `testA` and `testB`.
- `testA` is the same code as `testB`, which means that over time they will return about the same value.